# Flutter - Log Modal Bottom Sheet screen_view in analytics

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I've been tracking screen views by implementing `RouteAware` in stateful widgets that are stacked in the Navigator, together with a subscription in its Navigator `RouteObserver`. This is working fine.

Besides these PageRoutes, I also have a couple of **Modals** (eg `BottomModalSheet`) and **Dialogs** (eg `InfoDialogBox`) in my App.
Would it be possible to have a similiar approach for modals & dialogs, so that I could track time spent on that screen without having to explicitly call `setCurrentScreen`?

Thanks for the help!